# Why Kurento cannot record media stream from mobile to web when recording from web?

Tags: webrtc, kurento, recorder

I am not able to record the media stream taken from the onTrack callback from RTCPeerConnection, here is the code I want to use to record the incoming mobile video call from the web
I want to get a mediaStream from onTrack

```
this.myPeerConnection.ontrack = e => {
        this.webcamStreamRecieved = e.streams[0];
    };
```

I create a new RTCPeerConnection to connect to kurento and addTrack

```
this.webcamStreamRecieved.getTracks().forEach(track => {
            this.remoteRecordPeerConnection.addTrack(track, thís.webcamStreamRecieved);
        });
```

recorder.addRecordingListener not enabled in kurento, the generated file does not increase in size but stops at 0 bytes